# Android location/GPS icon in status bar

Tags: android, gps, location

As I'm testing my application on different phones, I'm experiencing an unprecedented behavior on my Galaxy S7 (Android 6.0)

I am requesting location updates at a frequency of 15 minutes. On all my other phones, the GPS icon appears in the status bar as soon as the code below runs:

GPSlocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 15 * 60 * 1000, 0, this);

However on my S7, if I don't bring down minTime to less than 5 minutes, the GPS icon either appears for a split second in the status bar, or does not appear at all. However a Log placed in onLocationChanged() tells me it is being called every 15 minutes, therefore it looks like the GPS is in fact enabled but the status bar does not reflect that.

Have you guys ever dealt with a phone where if minTime was too high, the GPS would simply never trigger onLocationChanged?

Comment: It might be that with too long a period, rather than keep the GPS on it turns it on for a second and then turns it off to save battery.

Comment: My concern here is the GPS not ever turning on. If it at least turns on at the requested interval, then I guess that's ok. Next thing I need to test is if onLocationChanged() actually returns something when it behaves like this.